# Why doesn't this left outer join query work properly? 

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a table that looks like this:

```
peter=> \d aggregated_accounts_by_month
Table "public.aggregated_accounts_by_month"
  Column   |  Type   | Modifiers 
-----------+---------+-----------
 xtn_month | date    | 
 account   | text    | 
 commodity | text    | 
 amount    | numeric | 
Indexes:
    "idx_aggregated_accounts_by_month_account" btree (account)
    "idx_aggregated_accounts_by_month_month" btree (xtn_month)
```

And another table that looks like this:

```
peter=> \d months
   Table "pg_temp_2.months"
  Column   | Type | Modifiers 
-----------+------+-----------
 xtn_month | date |
```

`months` contains this:

```
 xtn_month   
------------
 2011-01-01 
 2011-02-01 
 2011-03-01 
 2011-04-01 
 2011-05-01 
 2011-06-01 
 2011-07-01
```

`aggregated_accounts_by_month` contains this relevant data:

```
 xtn_month  |    account    | amount 
------------+---------------+--------
 2011-01-01 | Expenses:Fuel | 111.31
 2011-02-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  89.29
 2011-03-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  97.41
 2011-04-01 | Expenses:Fuel | 101.70
 2011-05-01 | Expenses:Fuel |   52.9
 2011-07-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  49.55
```

The query I'm trying to run is:

```
select 
    months.xtn_month,
    account,
    amount
from
    aggregated_accounts_by_month a
    left outer join months on months.xtn_month = a.xtn_month
where
    account = 'Expenses:Fuel'
order by
    xtn_month;
```

What I want this query to do is give me these results:

```
 xtn_month  |    account    | amount 
------------+---------------+--------
 2011-01-01 | Expenses:Fuel | 111.31
 2011-02-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  89.29
 2011-03-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  97.41
 2011-04-01 | Expenses:Fuel | 101.70
 2011-05-01 | Expenses:Fuel |   52.9
 2011-06-01 | Expenses:Fuel |
 2011-07-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  49.55
```

But it's actually giving me this:

```
 xtn_month  |    account    | amount 
------------+---------------+--------
 2011-01-01 | Expenses:Fuel | 111.31
 2011-02-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  89.29
 2011-03-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  97.41
 2011-04-01 | Expenses:Fuel | 101.70
 2011-05-01 | Expenses:Fuel |   52.9
 2011-07-01 | Expenses:Fuel |  49.55
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong. Any ideas? I'm running PostgreSQL 9.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

*Edit:* After thinking about this some more, I need to left outer join against not only months, but also against accounts. This query does exactly what I want:

```
select
    xtn_month,
    account,
    coalesce(amount, 0)
from
    (
        select
            xtn_month,
            account
        from
        (
            select
                distinct xtn_month
            from
                aggregated_accounts_by_month
        ) x
        cross join
        (
            select
                distinct account
            from
                aggregated_accounts_by_month
        ) y
    ) z
    left outer join aggregated_accounts_by_month
        using (xtn_month, account)
where
    account = 'Expenses:Fuel'
order by
    xtn_month;
```

ypercube's answer was *almost* right, except that it didn't fill in the `account` column. This query is of course rather expensive, what with that cross product in there. That's ok, though, because `aggregated_accounts_by_month` has a little under 2000 rows for over four years of data.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- reverse the order of the two tables in the `LEFT JOIN` and
- move the condition  from the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause.

.

```
select 
    months.xtn_month,
    a.account,
    a.amount
from
    months 
    left outer join aggregated_accounts_by_month a
        on  months.xtn_month = a.xtn_month
        and a.account = 'Expenses:Fuel'
order by
    xtn_month;
```

Comment: That totally works, and actually explains why my query wasn't working. The `account` column ends up null because it's not in the months table, and thus the `where` clause filters out that row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `aggregated_accounts_by_month` contains no `2011-06-01`. You might actually be looking for a full join:

```
select 
    months.xtn_month,
    account,
    amount
from
    aggregated_accounts_by_month a
    full join months on months.xtn_month = a.xtn_month
where
    account = 'Expenses:Fuel'
order by
    xtn_month;
```

Alternatively, left join as the other two answers suggest, i.e. `months`, then `aggregated_accounts_by_month`.